# Get paths of saved checkpoints from Pytorch-Lightning ModelCheckpoint

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-lightning, checkpointing

I am using PytorchLightning and beside others a `ModelCheckpoint` which saves models with a formated filename like `filename="model_{epoch}-{val_acc:.2f}"`

I then want to load these checkpoints again, for simplicity I want the best from `save_top_k=N`.
As the filename is dynamic I wonder how can I retrieve the checkpoint files *easily*.
Is there a built-in attribute in the `ModelCheckpoint` or the trainer that gives me the saved checkpoints?
For example like

```
checkpoint_callback.get_top_k_paths()
```

I know I can do it with `glob` and model_dir but wondering if there is a one line solution built in somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can retrieve the [best model path](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pytorch_lightning.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint.html?highlight=best_model#pytorch_lightning.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint) after training from the checkpoint

```py
# retrieve the best checkpoint after training
checkpoint_callback = ModelCheckpoint(dirpath='my/path/')
trainer = Trainer(callbacks=[checkpoint_callback])
model = ...
trainer.fit(model)
checkpoint_callback.best_model_path
```

To find all the checkpoints you can get the list of files in the `dirpath` where the checkpoints are saved.